# How to pass value using django-tables2

Tags: django-tables2

I'm looking for wat to link to tables. 
Clicking value in column would pass foreign key to function. This function would use it as a filter. 
I see that it is not taking this value to be passed.

tables.py

```
class tab_claim_cases(tables.Table):
    partnumber = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="{% url "case_details" %}idfactclaimcase={{ idclaim.idfactclaimcase }}">{{ partnumber.partnumber}}</a>')
    class Meta:
        model = Factclaim
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ("partnumber", "dateregistered.thedate", "dateinstalled.thedate", "dateremoved.thedate", "milage", "make", "claimreason" )
```

views.py

```
def case_details(request):
    filter = request.GET.get('idfactclaimcase', False)
    items = Factclaim.objects.filter(idfactclaimcase=filter)
    table = tab_claim_cases(items)
    return render(request, 'fact_claim.html', {'table': table})
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^case_details$', case_details, name='case_details')
```

Comment: Is this because  tables.TemplateColumn do not offer passing values?
Should I use Linkcolumn?

Answer (score 0):

How I solved is:

tables.py

```
class tab_claim_cases(tables.Table):
    partnumber = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="{% url "case_details" %}?idfactclaimcase={{ record.idfactclaimcase.idfactclaimcase }}">{{ record.partnumber.partnumber }}</a>')
    class Meta:
        model = Factclaim
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ("partnumber", "idfactclaimcase.thedate.thedate", "idfactclaimcase.description", "idfactclaimcase.manufacturedef")
```

views.py

```
def claim_cases(request):
    items = Factclaim.objects.exclude(idfactclaimcase__isnull=True)
    table = tab_claim_cases(items)
    return render(request, 'claim_cases.html', {'table': table})
```